# Forcing a section to begin on the bottom of the page instead of on a new page in memoir

Tags: memoir

I'm using the `memoir` class and have a page with enough whitespace at the bottom for the next section title and the first three lines of the first paragraph. However, once this paragraph becomes longer than 3 lines, both the paragraph and the section title are moved to the next page, leaving a lot of free space on the bottom of the other page.

Using `\enlargethispage` to add another line to the page works fine. The page then breaks after the first four lines. This, however, puts too much text on one page (the last line is then very close to the page number, see screenshot below). Is there another solution for this problem that would ideally put three lines on the first page and break after that?

[image: Screenshot]

Weirdly, this works okay on other pages. There is a large top-float on the following page, might that cause the issue?

Comment: You could always throw a {\parfillskip=0pt\newpage}\noindent into the text at the right spot.

Comment: If you are still interested in solving the problem, a minimal working example will help us figuring out the solution. Right now, the question seems to be unclear (you said it works on other instances).